# How to get objects from root to level 1 descendant in elastic search by using path_hierarchy?

Tags: elasticsearch, tree, parent-child, hierarchy

I am Using path_hierarchy to maintain tree like structure in Elastic search

```
PUT file-path-test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_path_tree": {
          "tokenizer": "custom_hierarchy"
        },
        "custom_path_tree_reversed": {
          "tokenizer": "custom_hierarchy_reversed"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "custom_hierarchy": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy",
          "delimiter": "/"
        },
        "custom_hierarchy_reversed": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy",
          "delimiter": "/",
          "reverse": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "file_path": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "tree": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "custom_path_tree"
          },
          "tree_reversed": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "custom_path_tree_reversed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below are the insert scripts

```
POST file-path-test/_doc/6
{
  "file_path": "/folder1"
}

POST file-path-test/_doc/7
{
  "file_path": "/folder1/folder2"
}

POST file-path-test/_doc/8
{
  "file_path": "/folder1/folder2/folder3"
}

POST file-path-test/_doc/9
{
  "file_path": "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4"
}
```

**So I want query to show only objects from root level to 1 level descendants objects
e.g if i get path  '/folder1/folder2' then query should return**

```
/folder1
/folder1/folder2
/folder1/folder2/folder3
```

It should not include below value

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4
```

Below query is returning whole tree values i.e from root to leaf nodes

```
GET file-path-test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
       "file_path.tree": "/folder1/folder2"
    }
  }
  }
```

**Result:**

```
/folder1
/folder1/folder2
/folder1/folder2/folder3
/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query-time file path will need to be converted to a comparable list of subpaths — identical to what your `custom_path_tree` analyzer would produce.

The heavy lifting can happen inside a [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) but in order to access `file_path.tree` members in such a script, a slight but important mapping modification is required:

```json
PUT file-path-test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      ...
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "file_path": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "tree": {
            "type": "text",
            "fielddata": true,                  <---
            "analyzer": "custom_path_tree"
          },
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Once that's done, use the following script:

```json
GET file-path-test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          def doc_tree = doc['file_path.tree'];    
          
          def folder_path_query = params.folder_path_query;
          def query_path_tree = [];
          def last_appended_folder = '';
          for (folder in /\//.split(folder_path_query)) {
            def folder_str = folder.toString();
            if (folder_str.length() > 0) {
              last_appended_folder += '/'+ folder_str;
              query_path_tree.add(last_appended_folder);
            }
          }

          def doc_in_query = doc_tree.stream().allMatch(folder -> query_path_tree.contains(folder));
          def query_in_doc = query_path_tree.stream().allMatch(folder -> doc_tree.contains(folder));
          
          def doc_tree_size = doc_tree.size();
          def query_path_tree_size = query_path_tree.size();
          
          // +1 for the closest descendant
          if (doc_tree_size <= query_path_tree_size + 1) {
            return doc_in_query || query_in_doc
          }
          
          return false
        """,
        "params": {
          "folder_path_query": "/folder1/folder2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All it does is that it reconstructs the directory tree of the parametrized `folder_path_query` such that the value streams of both trees (arrays) can be compared.